# Stored Procedure delete statement after return

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

So I'm tracking down a potential bug in a sync process I'm in charge of (written by someone else). When viewing one of the stored procedures that is being called, I noticed something peculiar. Based on my understanding of returns, anything after the return will not be returned. However, I am not positive if this is the case in SQL. Based on the chunk of SQL below, will the delete statement ever run? Or does the SP return information to signify whether rows were deleted (such as how many rows, whether it was successful, etc.)? I am assuming this is a bug in the SP, but want to confirm before taking action. Thanks in advance.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteSalesforce_Contacts]
AS
Return
Delete From dbo.Contacts Where IsDeleted = 1

GO
```

Comment: It's probably some testing/incomplete code remaining there, they forgot to put a FIX_ME there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) is pretty clear on this:

> "Exits unconditionally from a query or procedure. RETURN is immediate
>   and complete and can be used at any point to exit from a procedure,
>   batch, or statement block. Statements that follow RETURN are not
>   executed."

The delete statement won't be executed.

The `return` statement takes an optional parameter, but to use a query as value you would need to use a select in parentheses. Example:

```
return (select top 1 id from SomeTable)
```

Comment: That's what I figured, but I just couldn't imagine the person who wrote this would make that mistake. I guess mistakes happen to anyone! Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @parrotsnest: The intention with putting the `return` first in the procedure might be to disable the code in it for testing purposes, and accidentally left like that.

Comment: That may be the case, in which I'd think might make it a bad practice then due to this possibility?

Comment: @parrotsnest: Yes, it would be better to comment out code that should be disabled. If that leaves the procedure without code as in your case, you might also need to add a return to be able to save it.

Answer (score 0):

The delete would never happen when the proc is executed.

The only time a statement after the return is ever executed when a proc is run is if it was related to a goto process and the code was sent there and bypassed the return. This kind of code sometimes used to be written before Try Catch blocks were allowed in SQL Server to do something with errors.